# Grape-Swagger: Route Parameter issues

Tags: ruby, api, documentation, swagger, ruby-grape

I am using grape-swagger to show documentation on my Ruby API i'm building using Grape.

I am adding descriptions to all of my parameters on my endpoints but I can't seem to find anything about how to add descriptions to route parameters.

I have tried the following:

`route_param :monitor_name, type: String, desc: 'The name of the monitor that is being retrieved.' do`

and

`route_param :monitor_name, type: String, description: 'The name of the monitor that is being retrieved.' do`

but neither of those will display the actual description on the swagger UI.

Any ideas? 
Thanks for the help!

p.s. (the only thing I found in the [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) documentation is shown in the attach image)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
route_param :monitor_name, type: String, documentation: { desc:'The name of the monitor that is being retrieved.' }
```